# ASP.NET Core front-end developer workflow with VSCode and VS 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I haven't done any `cshtml` front-end development for a few years.

What's the current, generally accepted way for ASP.NET Core front-end developers to work across a range of tools on Windows?

By that, I mean a way to have the front-end JS build and the .NET project(s) also build and to work rapidly in the browser and code.

My thinking is.

- We have much better command line story around `dotnet` today.
- Some folk like VS Code.
- Some folk prefer VS 2019, and some like either, depending.
- We need to work on UI aspects sometimes.
- But we also need to attach a debugger and debug the server logic sometimes.
- The build server should have no problem, be simple, and rely mostly on build logic held in the repo.
- Tooling, and kicking off the whole build and serve process should be understandable and familiar.
- It should be pretty simple to get going after a team noob clones the repo.

My initial thought would be to setup NPM then use something like Gulp to kick off everything, including running `dotnet run`.

Then when running under the Visual Studio 2019 debugger, use the Task Runner Explorer to kick off the Gulp stuff but skip the `dotnet run` part.

(shame there doesn't seem to be a command line for start VS(Code or 2019) and attach debugger)

Now I'm expecting to get a "primarily opinion based" SO beating, but there are general trends and ideas that go into designing all these tools for how they can all play ball together and what the dev story looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much already described the process. However, I'll add a few things:

1. You don't need the `dotnet run` bit. Visual Studio and VS Code are both capable of debugging directly.
2. You can assign the gulp tasks to build tasks in Task Runner Explorer, so you really don't even then to think about running those directly. I'm not as sure on this aspect of VS Code, but I'm sure there's probably some extension to handle it, if it's not already built-in.
3. If you want true ease of development, the best thing you can do is use Docker. Just add a Dockerfile to each project that actually runs (i.e. not a class library) and set up the steps to build and run it there. In Visual Studio, you can right-click the project and choose Add > Docker Support, and it will actually generate a ready-made Dockerfile, though you may need to add a step or two to handle the client-side build steps. In any case, this then becomes truly click and run, with nothing to worry about. The story is even better when you use docker-compose, as then Visual Studio and VS Code can spin up your entire application stack all at once, including external dependencies such as a database, Redis instance, etc. If you haven't used Docker before, start now. It's absolutely revolutionary for development.

One note for CI/CD, as much as possible, you should add a YAML file to describe your CI/CD pipeline. Depending on the the actual provider you're using for build/release, there might be some differences, so consult the relevant documentation. (Azure DevOps, for example, doesn't currently support describing release pipelines in yaml, though you can still do your build that way.) In any case, this allows you to configure all this in code, and have it committed to source control.

You may consider the same for your infrastructure. Azure has ARM templates, AWS has CloudFormation, GCP has Deployment Manager. There's also third-party tools like Terraform or Ansible. All of these, in some form or fashion (usually JSON or YAML) allow you to define all the characteristics of the infrastructure you're going to deploy to and commit that to source control. This makes deployment and things like creating new environments as breeze.